# event.target.value returns undefined with semantic UI when I console log it

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set the state for when someone clicks on the checkbox. I can get this to work with a normal checkbox type but can't with semantic ui as my values are returned as undefined. 'Input name undefined. Input value undefined.' I was wondering if someone could help me out here.

Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input, Dropdown, TextArea, Form, Button, Header, Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class PageTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      programAgreement: false;

    }
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);


  }


  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    console.log(`Input name ${name}. Input value ${value}.`);

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

<Checkbox



placeholder="I Agree"
    name="programAgreement"
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.state.programAgreement}
    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can have two params every time onChange triggered.

```
onChange(event: SyntheticEvent, data: object)
event
React's original SyntheticEvent.
data
All props and proposed checked/indeterminate state.
```

try this below code:

```
  handleInputChange(event,data) {
    this.setState({
      [data.name]: !data.checked
    });
  }
```

[live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n4yqykmorm?module=/example.js)

Comment: Wait what ? onChange has two parameters?

Comment: yes semantic-ui-react onchange has tow params... check documentation if you not sure?????
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/checkbox/

Comment: Thanks you. After half and hour of searching I found this answer. Semantic should give at least one event handling example on its platform. @sathish kumar

Answer (score 1):

try to use second parameter

```
handleInputChange(e, data) {
  console.log(data);
  const value = data.type === "checkbox" ? data.checked : data.value;
  const name = data.name;

  console.log(value);
  console.log(name);

  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
};
```